# How to ensure UITableViewCell is visible?

Tags: iphone, ios4, xamarin.ios

I'm using an InputAccessoryView so a toolbar appears on top of my keyboard for an iPhone app.  When the keyboard appears it scrolls the UITableView up so the cell becoming first responder is in view.  When I tap "Next" on my keyboard which moves the focus to the next UITableView row the cell is beneath the InputAccessoryView now.

How can I ensure the active cell is in view and not covered up by the InputAccessoryView?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly you would like to scroll the table programatically so your highlighted cell is always the visible one? If so, you have a few choices for doing this:

```
tableView.ScrollToRow(indexPath, UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, true);
```

This will scroll to the cell given by the indexPath - if you don't have the indexPath handy, you could always use:

```
tableView.ScrollRectToVisible(new RectangleF(0, Ydisplacement, tableView.Width, tableView.Height), true);
```

(where Ydisplacement is how far down the table you'd like to scroll)

You could also use:

```
tableView.ScrollToNearestSelected(UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, true);
```

but I'm not sure if the cell you want will be selected. It's definitely worth experimenting with. 
This is just a few ideas to get your started but should be what you're looking for. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use UITableViewController instead of UIViewController, than the table view will scroll automatically.

Connect your UITableView to the TableView property of the UITableViewController (do not add it as a subview of the View property of the UITableViewController!).

Also make sure to set the AutoresizingMask property of your UITableView to FlexibleHeight

Example:

```
public class YourTableViewController : UITableViewController
{
    private UITableView _yourTableView;

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        _yourTableView = new UITableView(View.Bounds, UITableViewStyle.Plain);
        _yourTableView.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight;
        TableView = _yourTableView;
    }
}
```